# How to use php to explode string, remove extra characters

Tags: php, arrays, string, echo, explode

I've been using PHP for a while and came across an issue where turning a string into an array (explode), and then simply removing system output characters around each element was not easy to achieve.

I have a string of categories where the output needs to be handled:

```
2;#Ecosystems;#3;#Core Science Systems (CSS);#4;#Energy and Minerals;#5;#Director
```

I have tried this particular code below:

```
$text = "2;#Ecosystems;#3;#Core Science Systems (CSS);#4;#Energy and Minerals;#5;#Director";
$explode = explode('#' ,  $text);
foreach ($explode as $key => $value)
{
    ob_start();
    echo ''.$value.''; 
    $myStr = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

}
echo "$myStr"
```

The only element returned is:

```
 Director
```

Can someone point me in the right direction. I'd like to view the string like this:

```
Ecosystems; Core Science Systems (CSS); Energy and Minerals; Director
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$myStr = ob_get_contents();`

This will replace $myStr. What you're probably looking to do is add to it:

`$myStr .= ob_get_contents();`

Though looking at your required output, your code is not going to achieve what you want, because you're not removing the preceding part e.g. `#1;`.

Try this

```
$text = "2;#Ecosystems;#3;#Core Science Systems (CSS);#4;#Energy and Minerals;#5;#Director";
$text = preg_replace('/(#?[0-9];#)/', ' ', $text);
echo $text;
```

Output: `Ecosystems; Core Science Systems (CSS); Energy and Minerals; Director`

Comment: No problem. Stick a `+` after `[0-9]` if your numbers run into more than single digits.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not question-related, you overwrite your buffer with each foreach iteration, the fix is

> $myStr `.`= ob_get_contents();

Answer (score 1):

For this exact example you give you could change the explode to split on ;#

```
$text = "2;#Ecosystems;#3;#Core Science Systems (CSS);#4;#Energy and Minerals;#5;#Director";
$categories = array();
$explode = explode(';#' ,  $text);
foreach ($explode as $key => $value)
{
    if (!is_numeric($value)) {
        $categories[] = $value;
    }
}
echo implode("; ", $categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you place both ob_start() and ob_end_clean() inside the loop. Place them outside the loop:

```
ob_start();
foreach ($explode as $key => $value)
{
   echo ''.$value.''; 
   $myStr = ob_get_contents();
}
ob_end_clean();
echo "$myStr";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_split` and do it like this:

```
$result = implode(' ', preg_split('/#?\d+;#/', $text, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Answer (score 0):

this solves the problem, you can fine-tune the output:

```
$text = "2;#Ecosystems;#3;#Core Science Systems (CSS);#4;#Energy and Minerals;#5;#Director";
$explode = explode('#' ,  $text);
$myStr = '';
foreach ($explode as $key => $value)
{
  $myStr .= $value;
}
echo "$myStr"
```